# Fit ion-grid width to content and all cells in the same column should have the same width

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6, ion-grid

I have an ion-grid with multiple columns. I would like to make the columns fit to the content but the same column should have the same width (all cols having the width of the cell with the longest content). I know by setting `size="auto"`, the column can size itself based on the natural width of its content, but it results in cells in the same column are having different width. How should I do to achieve my target? Thanks a lot for helping.

html code

```
<ion-grid class="ion-margin">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="auto">No.</ion-col>
      <ion-col>Name</ion-col>
      <ion-col>Age</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let a of arr; index as i">
      <ion-col size="auto">{{ i + 1 }}</ion-col>
      <ion-col>{{ a.name }}</ion-col>
      <ion-col>{{ a.age }}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

If I remove size="auto", it results like this which is not what I want as the column width does not fit the content:

[image]

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102028/ionic-fit-ion-grid-with-to-content) seems like having the same question with me but the answer does not help me.

Comment: This is probably not a very good answer but if the idea is to use that column for something that won't change too much in terms of width (like the row index number), maybe setting something fixed like 64px could be a super easy way to achieve it.